# How to solve compilation error with missing packages

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, tidyverse

Tried to compile written Rstudio code but will not work because of missing package "digest."  I tried to install this package but it kept saying that :

```
xaringanExtra::use_scribble()
Error: package ‘digest’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
> reinstall packages.digest
Error: unexpected symbol in "reinstall packages.digest"
> knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, 
+ (echo = FALSE, 
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, 
(echo = FALSE,"
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:
 package ‘colorspace’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.3.0
```

The issue is that it is not a machine I had control over, so I am not responsible for installing software on the machine.  What is the possible remedy or work around this problem.  Thanks.

Tried to install the missing packages and I expected the program to work

Comment: is it possible to install R packages? Mostly, you can do this without admin. just try: `install.packages("digest")`

Comment: The error message suggests to me that your version of R is very old and needs updating.

Comment: Thanks Phil,

The machine is on a network and asking for Admin password.  So I can always request for an update.

Cheers.

Comment: Many thanks for all your comments.